# How to get random time within next hour from given time?

Tags: java, datetime, date

I have a object which returns DateTime. I need to generate a random time within next hour.

For example

```
ZonedDateTime date1 = ZonedDateTime.now(); // returns  2020-01-29T15:00:00.934
ZonedDateTime date2 = ZonedDateTime.now(); // returns  2020-01-29T15:45:00.233
ZonedDateTime convertedDate1;
ZonedDateTime convertedDate2;

//Conversion logic

assertEquals("2020-01-29T15:37:56.345", convertedDate1.toString());
assertEquals("2020-01-29T16:22:22.678", convertedDate2.toString());
```

Comment: can you please explain what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I think it’s been asked and answered before. My first search didn’t find an exact match to your question, but a number of similar questions, so if you search a bit harder, I would expect it to turn up. Only ignore the answers using the outdated `Date` or `Calendar` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generate random minutes between `0-60` using [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-) and add them to `ZonedDateTime`

```
ZonedDateTime result = date.plusMinutes(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(60));
```

In the same way you can add randomly generated seconds and nano seconds also

```
ZonedDateTime result = date.plusMinutes(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(58))
                               .plusSeconds(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(59))
                               .plusNanos(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(999));
```

**Note :** nextInt(int bound), nextLong(int bound) will generate between 0 (including) and specific bound (excluding)

> Returns a pseudorandom int value between zero (inclusive) and the specified bound (exclusive).

Comment: for random numbers between `0` and `59`(inclusive) better/more precise: `...nextInt(60)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
long leftLimit = 1L;
long rightLimit = 3600000L;
long generatedLong = leftLimit + (long) (Math.random() * (rightLimit - leftLimit));

 long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
 long randomTime = currentMillis + generatedLong;

  Time time = new Time(currentMillis);
```

I am getting just time but you can get date and time both.

Comment: The question appears to be about `ZonedDateTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. In this case I see no point in bringing on the `Time` class. It is poorly desgned and long outdated, was never meant for anything but sending and receiving a time of day to and from you SQL database, and is clearly not what the questioner was asking for.

Comment: the requirement was to get the random time of next hour, and I just give them an idea, It's their choice to use it or not :-)